# Warning: No such label 'RESPONSE TIME' for console.timeEnd()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

**Situation:**

I have a Node.js api that is called many times a second on a website.  I am using `console.time('RESPONSE TIME')` and `console.timeEnd('RESPONSE TIME')` to measure how long the api is taking to respond to the client on to each request.
Inside of the api, I am using a `Promise.all()` to aggregate responses from 4 different api's and then return a final response based on what the 4 apis returned.

**Issue:**

Everything works as expected except for an occasional warning logged `Warning: No such label 'RESPONSE TIME' for console.timeEnd()`.  Why is this and how do I properly avoid this?

I speculate that it's because Node is asynchronous and while one request may still be waiting for it's 4 api's to respond, another request will have finished and hit the `console.timeEnd()` ending both timers since they share the same name.  But I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: can't you just log `Date.now() - msStart` instead of using the console timing feature? that way, you don't have to worry about order of operations or rush conditions.

Comment: @dandavis I thought about that.  It's a solution but ideally I'd like to use `console.time()` since it's cleaner and that's what it's made for.  Every ms counts so I'd rather avoid using things like the `Date` object

Comment: Even I am thinking about the explanation you are giving but would like to know if that's the exact reason?

Comment: @SarasArya In regards to the original question?  I still haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your speculation is correct, you should have a unique label name for every api call.
Assuming every request has a unique identifier stored in req.id you can use the following:

```
console.time(`RESPONSE TIME request ${req.id}`)
// await api call
console.timeEnd(`RESPONSE TIME request ${req.id}`)
```

Comment: i get this error, even with the req.id, im only sure what i do between this its not finished or takes some time.

Comment: @emamones if `req.id` isn't working I bet you could just generate a new uuid on each request.